# Is it possible to train spark word2vec model in batch mode

Tags: apache-spark, word2vec

I am wondering if it is possible to train spark word2vec in batch mode. Or in other words, if it is possible to update the vocabulary list of a spark word2vec model which is already trained. 
My application is:
my paragraphs are located in multiple files, and when I use gensim i can do

```
class MySentences(object):
    def __init__(self, file_list, folder):
        self.file_list = file_list
        self.folder = folder

    def __iter__(self):
        for file in self.file_list:
            if 'walk_' in file:
                print file
                with open(self.folder + file, 'r') as f:
                    for line in f:
                        yield line.split()

model = Word2Vec(MySentences(files, fileFolder), size=32, window=5, min_count=5, workers=15)
```

i can even do

```
for epoch in range(10):
    model.train(MySentences(files, fileFolder))
```

I am wondering how I can do similar things in spark word2vec.

In spark, I found I can only do RDD union with multiple files as:

```
from pyspark.mllib.feature import Word2Vec 
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

inp1 = sc.textFile("file1").map(lambda row: row.split('\t'))
inp2 = sc.textFile("file2").map(lambda row: row.split('\t'))

inp = sc.union([inp1,inp2])
word2vec = Word2Vec().setVectorSize(4).setMinCount(1)
model = word2vec.fit(inp)
```

otherwise, if I train model with inp1, then inp2, the words from inp1 will be gone.

If i cannot do the training on batch mode, how can i update a trained model with new paragraphs in future?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can:

```
for idx in range(1, 100, 1):
    model = word2vec.fit(data.sample(False, 0.01))
    model.save(sc, path)
```

Not sure if the sample function always takes unseen data in this example.